# Add a simple route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a route that shows some data based on a string parameter like this:

```
http://whatever.com/View/078x756
```

How do I create that simple route and where to put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `global.asax.cs` file, you add the following lines:

```
routes.mapRoute(
    // The name of the new route
    "NewRoute",

    // The url pattern
    "View/{id}",

    // Defaulte route data                                     
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "078x756" });
```

Make sure you add them *before* the registration of the default route - the ASP.NET MVC Framework will look throught the routes in order and take the first one that matches your url. Phil Haack's [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) is a valuable tool when troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 1):

Routes are usually [configured](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) in the Application_Start method in Global.asax. For your particular case you could add a route before the Default one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Views",
    "View/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "somecontroller",
        action = "someaction",
        id = ""
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "home",
        action = "index",
        id = ""
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Routes are added in the `global.asax.cs`

Example of adding a route:

```
namespace MvcApplication1
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
               "WhatEver"
               "{View}/{id}",
               new {controller = "Home","action = "Index", id="abcdef"}
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
}
```